# Rename a variable used in multiple subclasses in Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have multiple sub classes all overriding a single super class (which is read-only).

Each sub class uses a method like the following:

```
@Override
public void overridingMethod(int n){
...
}
```

and I would like to change this to:

```
@Override
public void overridingMethod(int numberWithABetterName){
...
}
```

for all classes, without having to refactor it manually for each class.
Each class can also be found in the same folder, maybe there's a way to refactor a variable for all classes in a folder?

Comment: Can you modify the single super class for this change and once refactoring is applied to all subclasses, you revert the change to the parameter name?

Comment: @Jaywalker no, but never mind I did it manually

Answer (score 1):

Click on the Function Name:

- Choose Shortcut Shift + F6 (or)
- Right click and select Refactor -> Rename
- Function name changes to editable text box with rectangle border.
- Change function name. It will get reflected in all the occurrences including subclasses

[image: Rename the function]

Comment: This is the way to do it, but the OP wanted to change the argument name, not the method name. You can use the technique in your answer for the argument name, too.

Comment: But I can't edit the super class, so this doesn't work. The problem is that the super class is read-only.
Maybe it helps that the superclass already has the correct name, it's just the subclasses where the name is a simple 'e' which I'd like to change to a more usable variable name.

Comment: @Jonas just replace the word "function name" with "argument name" in this answer and then it will work. I.e. put your cursor on the "e" and do Refactor-Rename, and it will ask you if you want to rename the e in this method and all its overriding methods.